# Helvetica Neue font in iOS 14 App

Tags: law

Some times ago I've received a legal issue from monotype.com. They told that I was using font Helvetica Neue in my iOS app since 2015 to 2020 and now I need to pay for this font for all these years. I was shocked by that. I thought that this font is free for using in iOS app and it always was. Also, this font [preinstalled](https://developer.apple.com/fonts/system-fonts/#preinstalled) in iOS and macOS.

Can anyone help me and answer the question - can I use font Helvetica Neue in iOS 14 App for free?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is legal if you use the font preinstalled in iOS.

In this case, Monotype is wrong.

Comment: yeah, I think the same, thanks for your answer!